# Подскажите, как заменить числа, кратные 10 в массиве из 100 значений на число, которое будет вводится пользователем

Tags: c#

Вот код, который создаёт и выводит массив, но я не знаю, как заменить вышеописанные числа:

```
int[] a = new int[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                a[i] = i + 1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("a[{0}] = {1,2}", i, a[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

Только начинаю программировать, поэтому не совсем понимаю хода логики в этом деле. Помогите пж.

Comment: Кратность 10 можно проверить с помощью оператора `%`. `if` вам уже знаком?

Comment: Вы знаете как записать число в элемент массива, также и замену делайте - присваивайте новое число поверх старого.

Comment: В цикле `if (a[i] % 10 == 0) { a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); }`

Comment: Простите, я так и не понял, что делать с этим кодом. Мне непонятно, в какой части кода надо написать конструкцию if, потому что вне цикла for переменная i перестаёт действовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

напишите еще один цикл:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
   if (a[i] % 10 == 0) 
      a[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Благодарствую. Всего вам хорошего!